# What is a good backup method for Azure SQL?

Tags: backup, azure-sql-database

I maintain a Azure SQL database with the Basic plan. 7 days point in time restore is enough for our daily needs. What we are looking to improve is a daily backup outside Azure in the case that we lose access to our Azure subscription for whatever reason.

I have tried using SQLBackupAndFTP with snapshots enabled. Unfortunately it only works on the first backup and consecutive backups then fail. If I crate a new database I get the same behavior. I do not want to disable snapshots since I cannot guarantee that no write operations are done during the backup and I do not want the backup strategy to affect the availability of the web app using it.

Comment: The process that SQLBackupAndFTP uses is the supported method for Azure.  But it looks like there is an issue with how that application does it.  If you do the same thing but issue the commands yourself, it appears to work just fine.  (i.e. create database snapshot, export dacpac to storage account, drop snapshot).

Comment: I feel better hearing that I am not the only one with this issue. Creating Snapshots with T-SQL or PowerShell and dacpac exports does indeed work when I do it myself.